# PDF files shown on Chrome have no spaces

Tags: 10.04, google-chrome

Why while viewing PDF files on ubuntu on Chrome no spaces are shown?

Is it my problem or it's same for everyone?

If I open that file in Firefox it asks me to download it, but I can't see it without downloading.

EDIT: maybe anyone knows how to make it automatically download like in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Chrome builtin PDF viewer. Open `chrome://plugins/` in your address bar and click disable.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been [reported and fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64172). The fix should show up in Google Chrome 22.0.1223.0 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn

It will open up the PDF in Google Docs Viewer.